# Custom google map show users markers

Tags: xamarin

I want to create google map that show any logged users in map with marker. if any user open the app can show all other users around, in brief how to show all users in map , please help

Comment: What part don't you understand?  Do you want to know how to place markers on a map?  Or how to determine a users location?  Or how to share locations between multiple users of an app?

Comment: thanks, I want users to share locations and every users can show others location in map

Comment: You will need some sort of central server to register users location and broadcast them to other users.  There is no simple answer to this - you'll have to design and build something.

Comment: Ok, if I do that how to bind this to map

Comment: loop through the list of users and add a marker to the map for each one.

Comment: I want users enter his location info and automatically appears on map

Comment: Have you bothered to read the docs?  Things like getting a users location and adding markers to maps are amply documented.  If you have a specific problem that you are trying to solve, please post the relevant code and we'll try to help you.  But I'm not to going to post a step-by-step explanation of something that has already been documented hundreds of times.

Comment: thanks, I have another problem please help me, I have an app when debug on device its open and close without error